# Run PHP function from parent file

Tags: php, function, php-include

I need some help for a problem i'm facing.
I've look on the web but i only found more usual issues which cannot solve mine.

The main idea is to run PHP functions like `get_included_files()`, `get_defined_vars()`, `debug_backtrace()` from the parent file.

In my code i have a PHP file, let's call it A.php which is including another PHP file, let's say B.php.
I would like to run for exemple `get_included_files()` into B.php to get the files included in A.php.

Something similar to parent:: but for PHP files and not oriented object programming.
I'm aware that it could be a security flaw, that's why i'm not sure it is possible, but i ask to be sure.

To be the clearest possible, here is an example :

A.php

```
include 'B.php';
include 'C.php';
include 'D.php';

get_includes();
```

B.php

```
function get_includes()
{
    $included_files = get_included_files();
    print_r($included_files);
}
```

And i need the `$included_files` var to contain `array('B','C','D')`.
My problem is the PHP functions getting the included files from the file it's launched in, not from the parent (with this code, the `$included_files` is empty).

Comment: removed unnecessary words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is an interpreter, and interpretation will be strings. So the file a.php try to include files in the following order:

```
include 'С.php';
include 'D.php';
include 'B.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example:

a.php

```
function a(){
    echo "a";
}

function b(){
    echo "b";
}
```

b.php

```
include "a.php";

echo a();//echoes a

echo b();//echoes b
```

Comment: I was under the impression that the OP wanted to run functions such as get_included_files, from file a, such that it would return the values for file B. @Jean-Loup-Becquet, is that the case?

Comment: Yes that's it, i'd like to run PHP functions (not defined in my files) to get the parent file values.

Comment: you want to run something which is not defined??

Comment: It is defined, they are PHP functions like this http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php but they aren't defined in my files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would solve your problem, but you can also execute these function in the parent file, assign the result to a variable, and read this variable in included files.

For instance:

A.php

```
$a = 1;

$files = get_included_files();
$vars = get_defined_vars();

include 'B.php';

$b = 2;

$files = get_included_files();
$vars = get_defined_vars();

include 'C.php';
```

B.php

```
echo 'B<br /><pre>';
print_r($files);
print_r($vars);
echo '</pre>';
```

C.php

```
echo '<br />C<br /><pre>';
print_r($files);
print_r($vars);
echo '</pre>';
```

It will give an output that looks like this:

```
B

Array
(
    [0] => A.php
)
Array
(
    [...]
    [a] => 1
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => A.php
        )
)


C

Array
(
    [0] => A.php
    [1] => B.php
)
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [files] => Array
        (
            [0] => A.php
            [1] => B.php
        )
    [vars] => Array
        [...]
    [b] => 2
)
```

Note that you can't get info about files and vars that are included/defined after the call to the function, so anyway from B.php you can't know that C.php and D.php will be included later.

Comment: That's what i was thinking to do if i don't find any solution, and yes you are right, my actual code doesn't give the complete list of included files. Actually my real code is using a function, i will edit my post to correct the example.

Comment: Then that's strange because when I run your example as updated, it does print A.php, B.php, C.php and D.php.
What PHP version are you using?